# CRM Date-Time field

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have a CRM date-time field on Form. I have disabled the field on load. I enable this field on click of a custom button. However, when I enable the field, the values in the time picker are disabled i.e. i cannot choose the value in the picklist. however i can manually enter values in textbox. this is happening only for the time picker. the Date picker works just fine.
When i load the form in editable mode, the same script runs fine and lets me select values in the time picker
Help would be appreciated since i am trying to solve this since 2 days.
thanx!

Comment: can you post the javascript code you are using?

Answer (score 1):

CRM 2011 Bug.  Try unchecking "read only" on the date-time field itself in the form developer, and then use javascript to disable or enable it conditionally.